# Mutliply two dataframe on specified index

Tags: python, pandas

I am a bit lost on this one. Any help would be appreciated.

First dataframe:

```
            2020-08-03    2020-08-04
currency                            
1WO       8.255000e+00  8.137000e+00
ADH       6.349000e-02  6.388000e-02
...                ...           ...

XRP       3.292000e+01  3.184000e+01

[130 rows x 2 columns]
```

second dataframe:

```
                          2020-08-03    2020-08-04
app_id      currency                            
45334         1WO       2.614163e+05  2.614163e+05
              ADH       8.403654e+05  8.403654e+05
...                              ...           ...
23423         FRT       1.078614e+03  1.057127e+03
              WES       7.844820e+06  7.936699e+06

[148 rows x 2 columns]
```

The code:

```
jpy_bal = first_df.multiply(second_df, axis= 0, level='currency').fillna(0).astype(float)
```

The error:

```
   "Index._join_level on non-unique index " "is not implemented"
NotImplementedError: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is problem there are duplicates in `first_df.index`:

```
#simulate error
print (first_df)
          2020-08-03  2020-08-04
currency                        
1WO          8.25500     8.13700
1WO          0.06349     0.06388
XRP         32.92000    31.84000

jpy_bal = first_df.multiply(second_df, axis= 0, level='currency').fillna(0).astype(float)
print (jpy_bal)
NotImplementedError: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented
```

Possible solution is aggregate by `sum` or `mean` per index:

```
first_df = first_df.groupby(level=0).sum()
print (first_df)
          2020-08-03  2020-08-04
currency                        
1WO          8.31849     8.20088
XRP         32.92000    31.84000

jpy_bal = first_df.multiply(second_df, axis= 0, level='currency').fillna(0).astype(float)
print (jpy_bal)
                   2020-08-03    2020-08-04
app_id currency                            
45334  1WO       2.174589e+06  2.143844e+06
       ADH       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
23423  FRT       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
       WES       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
```

Or remove duplicates per index:

```
first_df = first_df[~first_df.index.duplicated()]
print (first_df)
          2020-08-03  2020-08-04
currency                        
1WO            8.255       8.137
XRP           32.920      31.840

jpy_bal = first_df.multiply(second_df, axis= 0, level='currency').fillna(0).astype(float)
print (jpy_bal)
                   2020-08-03    2020-08-04
app_id currency                            
45334  1WO       2.157992e+06  2.127144e+06
       ADH       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
23423  FRT       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
       WES       0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
```

Comment: thanks. Indeed there is a same index label but it is in the multiindex of the first dataframe. The number has to remain separated. I cannot sum or mean them because they do have the same `app_id` label. Is there another way please?

Comment: @delalma - In first DataFrame are not duplicated index?

Comment: @delalma - So `print (first_df.index.has_duplicates)` return `False` ?

Comment: @delalma - hmmm, so there is MultiIndex in both DataFrames?

Comment: My apologize you were right about the duplicate in the first dataframe

Comment: @delalma - No problem, its happens ;) Nice day!